# Maximum Capacity for BULK INSERT from files such as CSV

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am receiving CSV files from an external source with emails. Sometimes I may receive over 200k worth of emails. What is the maximum amount of rows that BULK INSERT can import into temporary tables. Does it make a difference between temp and perm tables. And is it more about the amount of rows or the memory processed by the query.

```
BULK INSERT tmpImportTable FROM 
'C:\name\data\sample.csv' 
WITH ( FORMAT='CSV' , FIELDTERMINATOR = ',' )
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware, `bcp` and `BULK INSERT` don't have a maximum number of rows. Why would you want to import into a temporary table though? As soon as the connection is closed the data would be lost; so with `bcp` that would be as soon as the command complete.

Comment: That's because the emails are constantly changing and the requests as well. I don't want to have to include 200k emails in an IN Statement.

Comment: an `IN` statement with 200K expressions would almost certainly kill any query; but I'm not sure what your comment is actually in reference to.

Comment: a general direction would be to load your initial load and mark them with a UTC date; and then have a sql server job run (on your desired schedule) to pull incrementals ; just a suggestion. We clearly do not know what your design is and what your end goal is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bulk insert won't bat an eye at 200,000 rows. As far as where you put it, a persisted table is probably a better bet as:

1. It won't be removed if the connection closes
2. It won't put the burden on tempdb (a resource shared across all databases and many processes)

As far as memory is concerned, bulk insert should handle all the batching required to keep from blowing out your memory.

Also, it should be faster if the table into which you load the data doesn't have an index on it. We model our data uploads with

- A "raw" table, which has no indices or constraints on it, into which we bulk upload our data
- A "presentation" table, which is the place we actually want the data to end up (which has indices, etc.)
- A "workoff" procedure, which does the movement, batching and/or manipulation of the data between the raw table, and the presentation table.